# Embedding NodeJs vs JXCore in Another Application

Tags: node.js, embed, jxcore

I'm looking to embed Node within another application that has a C/C++ interface. I'm aware that it can be done with Node, but it requires a bit of work to turn Node into a shared library rather than an executable. Would JXCore potentially be a better alternative for embedding within another application?

Answer (score 0):

Code from [sample repo](https://github.com/obastemur/JXcoreWindowsEmbedded):

```
JXValue result;
JX_Evaluate(
    "var arr = process.natives.sampleMethod('String Parameter', {foo:1}); \n"
    "console.log('result: ', arr, 'length:', arr.length ); \n"
    "setTimeout(function() { \n"
    "  console.log('end!'); \n"
    "}, 100);",
    "myscript", &result);

JX_Free(&result);
```